# get multiple same views from MEF plugin in a mvvm way

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef

I am trying to develop a MEF plugin software, use notepad++ as an example, 
each tab will show a view that imported from each plugin.

the following interface would provide one instance of ConfigView after MEF composition.
but how to create multiple instances of ConfigView?

```
public interface IPluginA:IPlugin {
    // View, user control
    FrameworkElement CongfigView { get; }
}
```

--------Possible Solution--------------------------------------------------------------------

Actually, I am trying to use it in AvalonDock, and found avalonDock needs dataTemplate to create multiple 
views. In this way, plugins only need to provide one view data template.

```
internal class PanesTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector {


    private DataTemplate _fileViewTemplate;
    public DataTemplate FileViewTemplate {
        get {
            return _fileViewTemplate;
        }
        set { _fileViewTemplate = value; }
    }

    public DataTemplate FileStatsViewTemplate {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public PanesTemplateSelector() {
        // convert from usercontrol to data template
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(FileView));
        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
        dt.VisualTree = factory;

        _fileViewTemplate = dt;
    }

    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container) {

        var itemAsLayoutContent = item as LayoutContent;

        if (item is FileViewModel)
            return FileViewTemplate;

        if (item is FileStatsViewModel)
            return FileStatsViewTemplate;

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: not clear what you are asking, please edit

Comment: Is this clear? Thanks

Comment: Can you keep array of views instead of one? FrameworkElement CongfigView[] { get; }?

Comment: You are right, if host need one more View, just ask plugin to create one in array. Thanks.

Comment: I just post a comment as an answer, please don't forget to mark as answer if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep multiple views, instead of one... You can keep List or FrameworkElement[] based on if you want to create new ones dynamically or not

```
public interface IPluginA:IPlugin {
    // View, user control
    IList<FrameworkElement> CongfigViews { get; }
}
```

Comment: One more question, how to ask plugin to add a new configView? Use another method (AddNewConfigView) in the interface?

Comment: You can call ConfigView.Add but using a method is defiantly better. Than just make ConfigView of type IEnumerable<FrameworkElement>, and use underlying ObservableCollection, which will give ability to refresh main view on new vew add